# Python/Selenium Text File Output Loop

Tags: python, selenium, text, text-files, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having trouble with a loop writing to a text file. I'm trying to create a tab delimited text file that writes an ID, date, time, sequence number, and text from a transcript to a line, then starts a new line every time it reaches bold text.

When there is only 1 ID in my company_list, everything works great and it produces this example below:

[image]

However, as soon as I add an additional ID to the company_list, it produces this:

[image]

It looks like when a second company ID is added, that a new line is placed after every ID for some unknown reason. What's even weirder is that when the loop runs the last company ID in the list, that data is formatted correctly. There are no errors produced at all. If anyone has any idea what is going on here I would really appreciate it.

Code snippet below:

```
company_list = open('Company_List.txt')
for line in company_list:
   company_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='SearchTopBar']")))
   company_id.send_keys(line + Keys.ENTER)
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)

   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Transcripts").click()
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)

   driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Q1 2018").click()

   date = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl01__header__dateLabel"]').text
   struct_time = time.strptime(date, "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M %p")

   speaker = 1
   p_tag = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
   file = open("q1_2018.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8-sig')
   for i in range(3,len(p_tag) - 6):
      element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl01__bodyRow"]/td/p[' + str(i) + ']')
      weight = int(element.value_of_css_property('font-weight'))
      if weight == 700:
         file.write('\n' + line + '\t' + str(struct_time[0]) + str(struct_time[1]) + str(struct_time[2]) + '\t' + str(struct_time[3]) + str(struct_time[4]) + '\t' + str(speaker) + '\t')
         file.write(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl01__bodyRow"]/td/p[' + str(i + 1) + ']').text + ' ')
         speaker = speaker + 1
      else:
         file.write(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl01__bodyRow"]/td/p[' + str(i) + ']').text + ' ')
   file.close()
```

Comment: i think `file.write('\n'` after `if weight == 700:` is creating an issue. why you are adding new line in between. add new line at the end of the loop only.

Comment: I place it inside the IF loop because I only want a new line after bold text, not after every i in the FOR loop. I'm certainly not experienced so if there's a better way to write that I welcome it. Also, the phantom new line is being inserted **after** the company ID (line). So I just don't understand how that could even happen where it's happening.

Comment: and what if your id is bold?

Comment: It can't be, I read the IDs in from a text file I created. The bold text I'm looking for is from the web page I'm scraping.

Comment: then maybe there's a newline in your textfile

Comment: A link to the page or some sample HTML is needed.

Comment: @bobrobbob You're right, when I use "for line in company_list" it's reading 658776\n instead of 658776. What's the best way to prevent this?

Comment: use `rstrip()` function

Comment: I was just about to write that I did that, thank you so much!